# RouteLink linking to the current page instead of the route it was supposed to

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm trying to link to a route using a specific route. It was working before I started migration from MVC 5 to Core.

This is how the route was configured before:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "DefaultOrgRout",
           url: "db/{OrgCode}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

This is how my endpoints are configured now:

```
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            //endpoints.MapControllers();
            //endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "DefaultOrgRout",
                pattern: "db/{OrgCode}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

        });
```

And the `RouteLink` call is as follow:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Manage Users", "DefaultOrgRout", new { Controller = "Account", action = "Index" }, new { @id = "MainMenumanageUser" })
```

Comment: And did you receive an error?

Comment: No errors. The generated link from `RouteLink` is the same as the current URL user is at.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `OrgCode` parameter to match the `DefaultOrgRout` route template, like:

```
@Html.RouteLink("Manage Users", "DefaultOrgRout", new { controller = "Account", action = "Index", OrgCode="123", @id = "MainMenumanageUser" })
```

If you do not specify it the `OrgCode` is empty, and the URL is generated by using the second template.

Or you can define the `OrgCode` default value in the `MapControllerRoute()` call.